# Are folder icons changeable in Chrome's bookmarks bar?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Is is possible to change folder icons in the bookmarks bar in Google Chrome?

I'm looking for ways to organize the bookmarks I maintain locally in Google Chrome. I'm on a netbook, so screen space is limited, and I'm using folders to keep things sorted. I'm very visually oriented, and changing the icons (or even the colors) would enable me to find things more rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not officially supported at this time:

[Customizing the favicon of a bookmark.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18826#c0)

If that changes, of I hear of a way to do this that isn't dicey, will update this.