# Has Chrome allowed bookmark folder icon changing yet?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Within Chrome's bookmark bar, you can add folders.

[image: Example Bookmark Bar]

As far as I can tell, these are not yet editable to give them more descriptive images. Does anyone know if this is still the case, and if they have a way around it - mind sharing?

Sources I have checked like this [superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/166245/are-folder-icons-changeable-in-chromes-bookmarks-bar) and a few others, were very old (3+ years old), so I wasn't sure if any leeway had been made since then.

Answer (score 1):

I just searched the internet for this feature and came up with 'nothing'.

1. A [thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JRw5QDT3T7U) on Google product forums doesn't give very much hope on this subject:
2. Some threads suggest that using a Chrome plugin called 'I hate your favicon' could maybe solve this, but I couldn't figure out how...

Comment: Thank you. You came back with pretty much the same results as I did.